# How to overwrite an nginx variable

Tags: nginx

How can I overwrite a variable's previously set value?  In the below scenario, when `$http_x_forwarded_proto = "https"` `$redirectToHttps` is not being set to false but remaining true.  I'd expect this to overwrite the value but it doesn't appear to be doing so.  How can I do this?

```
location / {

    set $redirectToHttps false;
    set $environment "${APP_ENV}";

    # determine if we should force https based on the environment
    if ($environment = "production") {
        set $redirectToHttps true;
    }
    if ($environment = "staging") {
        set $redirectToHttps true;
    }

    # determine if we should force https based on the protocol
    if ($scheme = "https") {
        set $redirectToHttps false;
        return 200 "redirectToHttps-scheme: false";
    }
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "https") {
        set $redirectToHttps false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$http_x_forwarded_proto` is actually set to `https`?

Comment: @VBart - Yes, I've confirmed that.

Comment: How do you check that `$redirectToHttps` remains `true`?

Comment: Same way I'm checking `$scheme = "https"`, add a `return 200 "some text";`

Comment: If you use something like `if ($redirectToHttps) { return 200 "some text"; }`, then it's expected to be always true.

Comment: Ah.... I didn't realize that.  So I need to check numeric values (1 or 0) or something similar...

Comment: This solved my problem, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables in nginx are just strings, there's no such thing as binary flags like `true` or `false`.

According to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) of the `if` directive:

> A condition may be any of the following:
>
> - a variable name; false if the value of a variable is an empty string or “0”;
> - ...

so `true` and `false` equally evaluate to true in expression `if ($var) { ... }`.